# onTouchListener taking long to change backgroung of buttons, Android

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

In my application the background of buttons should change to another one when the user touch, and get back to the original one when the finger is off, my problem is that touching for a long period makes it change while touching for a short one, doesn't!! here's how I implemented that:

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_bb_e_l);
b.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_bb_e_l_selec);
                    break;}

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                    b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_bb_e_l);
                    break;}
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `drawable` and `shape` to implement it.

1. Create a file such `btn_bg.xml` in `res/drawable`
2. `btn_bg.xml`'s content:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <item android:state_pressed="true" 
             android:drawable="@drawable/button_bb_e_l_selected"/>
       <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_bb_e_l"/>
   </selector>
   ```
3. Set background to your button:

   ```
   <Button
           android:background="@drawable/btn_bg"/>
   ```

Comment: should I remove the java code ? I mean the onTouch section!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not required to use onTouch, you can create a style with background set to drawable.  Create that drawable as xml that uses selectors and set the selectors' different states, state_pressed="true" and state_pressed="false" and apply the colors to those states.  Then use that style on the buttons you want.